# Android Emulator cannot be started anymore (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-emulator, adt

For reasons unknown to me, today the Android emulator that comes with the ADT plugin for Eclipse decided to stop working and take a vacation.

What happens is that the emulator window opens, the android logo starts flashing (and continues to get animated forever) and... nothing. It just stays there.

The log ( http://pastebin.com/Vbcttrjs ) shows that it's tries to do something, gets an exception and closes the vm, then starts over. I have been unable to figure out what's wrong. I tried different API levels in the AVD, installed the newest version of Eclipse and set up ADT again, rebooted the computer and checked the "wipe user data" option when launching the virtual device, but nothing helped.

I'm using OSX (unfortunately) and trying to learn programming android apps, which was going well until the IDE started failing me :(

Edit:
New day, new error. I tried starting a virtual device with API level 17 just now. This one simply crashes after a few seconds. Log: http://pastebin.com/d1Q6zaW0

I've downloaded the ADT bundle today instead of just getting the normal eclipse and installing the ADT plugin and SDKs. Exactly the same behavior.

Edit2: Just now I tried `rm -r ~/.android`. Didn't help either. I am at my wits end.

Comment: start your emulator from avd and choose "wipe data" option.

Comment: start emulator with wipe user data, or else kill and start adb server again.

Comment: I already check wipe user data every time i start it from AVD. Not sure how to kill adb server, but I already rebooted the computer, which will have killed any running processes.

Answer (score 1):

None of the x86 images for OSX is broken. I use them all the time and they work perfectly fine. Please make sure you have set up from SDK path correctly on Preference->Android->SDK location. Also remember to check use host GPU option and set memory to not more than 600MB. can you please try with API level 19 and let us know what you see.

Thanks

Comment: I will have the chance to try again next week. However as I have stated, this happens with all API levels. I have tried several resolutions and memory ranging from 343MB to 1024MB and heap sizes ranging from 32MB to 128MB. Both with "use host GPU" checked and unchecked. I have tried both setting up eclipse (and downloading SDKs seperately) for android development as well as getting the android bundle, which comes with the SDKs and ready to use (yes I checked the paths in the SDK manager). In all instances, it either crashed or just got stuck in some loop and never started (see error log).

Comment: Are you using HAXM? If yes, the memory allocated for HAXM should be greater than the memory that you are using on your emulator.

Comment: Nope, no HAXM. At least I never installed it and I get a message when starting the emulator that reads something like "HAX not found" (can't remember the exact message).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the problem (I can't believe how stupid this is): When getting some more API-Levels over the SDK-Manager, I probably forgot to uncheck the updates (I generally avoid to update while developing something). It seems that every single x86 image (I used them since they run faster) for the android emulator is now broken on OSX at least. When I set `CPU/ABI` to `armeabi` again, everything started working, albeit somewhat slower.

And this, kids, is why I avoid updating if it's not necessary (security/features).